# UITableView cell with drawer effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm looking for a way to implement a UITableView cell with drawer effect in order to display people name with details on each people.
Indeed, I want that when I click on a cell, it opens an other bigger cell below with the details of the parent cell.

How can I do that ? I have to add an other cell in the table view and reload the table view ?
How can I get an effect for the opening of the details cell ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out this example -- https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Cookbook/tree/master/C10/07%20-%20Action%20Rows

This is source code from Erica's iOS 6 Cookbook.

Comment: Link in broken. This is why you should include code from the link in your answer.